# curve_fit plot generates a straight line when implementing guess and lapse rate separately for sigmoid function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I need to generate psychometric fitting plots for a series of data and I have a working script that was able to do so when I:-

1) Use the default sigmoid formula and
2) Have the lapse rate added onto the sigmoid function with the guess rate set to 0.

However, setting the guess rate more than 0 outside the formula resulted in flat lines. This wouldn't happen if I set the lapse rate set outside the sigmoid function as an independent but fixed variable by itself. Any idea what went wrong down here?

The following code is the one the generates the two straight lines.
Data for this particular plot is:-

[0, 2.0, 9.0, 11.0, 14.0] values inserted to ysdata

[3.0, 7.0, 14.0, 19.0, 20.0] values inserted to ycdata

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import os
import csv

C1adaptS = 0
CN2adaptS = 0
N3adaptS = 0
NS4adaptS = 0
S5adaptS = 0
C1adaptC = 0
CN2adaptC = 0
N3adaptC = 0
NS4adaptC = 0
S5adaptC = 0

#Paste filename to be analysised here (The .csv file)
filename = 'PartID_AA_20160302_1332.csv'

#Change directory to file's location
os.chdir('C:\Users\Aaron\Dropbox\JitterAdapt\Dotty Simplified (latest dot exp)\Dotty Simplified (Full Experiment Folder)')

loadcsv = open(filename, 'r')
for line in loadcsv.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    #Split the words within the line
    trialnum, stimulus, stimulus_location, response, more_sin_like, sin_adapt = line.split(',')
    if stimulus == 'C1' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '1':
        C1adaptS += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'CN2' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '1':
        CN2adaptS += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'N3' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '1':
        N3adaptS += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'NS4' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '1':
        NS4adaptS += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'S5' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '1':
        S5adaptS += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'C1' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '0':
        C1adaptC += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'CN2' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '0':
        CN2adaptC += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'N3' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '0':
        N3adaptC += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'NS4' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '0':
        NS4adaptC += 1.
    elif stimulus == 'S5' and more_sin_like == '1' and sin_adapt == '0':
        S5adaptC += 1.

SinAdaptList = [C1adaptS, CN2adaptS, N3adaptS, NS4adaptS, S5adaptS]
ConsAdaptList = [C1adaptC, CN2adaptC, N3adaptC, NS4adaptC, S5adaptC]

n = 20 #divide y-axis data by the number of trials in the experiment

guess = 0.05 #Set the minimum chance level
#lapse = 0.05 #The lapse rate. 0.01 = 1%

# The sigmoid function as defined is only applicable to a simple experiment where a single stimulus is 
# detected (nor not) and where the participant makes no errors. We need two new values;
# a ‘guessing’ value, that is the probability that the participant with get correct if they simply guess, 
# and a ‘lapsing’ probability, that is the estimated number of trials in which the participant will make a mistake.
# As an example, a 2AFC (two alternative forced choice) task forces the participant to choose between two stimuli, 
# the probability of getting the correct stimuli by chance is 0.5 so we set the value of the guess variable to 0.5. 
# The lapse variable can be found from the data. These two variables need to shift and scale the Sigmoid function.
# Instead of having a minima at 0 we need the minima of our sigmoid to match the guessing rate (0.5) 
# in our example so we add 0.5. We then need to scale the sigmoid to fit (adding 0.5 to 1 is 1.5 so 
# we need to rescale back to 1), this is achieved by dividing by (1-guessing rate) that is the bit left 
# over between 0 and 1 when the guess it taken out. Finally we can account for the lapse rate by taking a 
# ‘bit off the top’     

#The scaled sigmoid function
def sigmoidscaled(x, x0, k, lapse):
    F = (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) 
    z = guess + (1-guess-lapse)/F
    return z


#The data points in x-y coordinates
xdata = np.array([ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
ysdata = np.array([C1adaptS/n, CN2adaptS/n, N3adaptS/n, NS4adaptS/n, S5adaptS/n])
ycdata = np.array([C1adaptC/n, CN2adaptC/n, N3adaptC/n, NS4adaptC/n, S5adaptC/n])


#popt = 50% point. pcov = covariance. Fit the sigmoid function to the data.
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ysdata)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ycdata)

#Start and End of x-axis, in spaces of n. The higher the n, the smoother the curve.
x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
#The sigmoid values along the y-axis, generated in relation to the x values and the 50% point.
#The * in front of popt when you plot will expand out the terms into the x0 and k that func is expecting.
ys = sigmoidscaled(x, *popt)
yc = sigmoidscaled(x, *popt2)

pylab.plot(xdata, ysdata, 'o', label='sin adapted', color = 'blue')
pylab.plot(xdata, ycdata, 'o', label='cons adapted', color = 'red')
pylab.plot(x,ys, label='sin fit', color = 'blue')
pylab.plot(x,yc, label='cons fit', color = 'red')
#y axis range.
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
#Replace x-axis numbers as labels and y-axis numbers as percentage
xticks([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], ['C1','CN2','N3','CN4','S5'])
yticks([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], ['0%','20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is kind of hard to say what is going wrong without the access to the data. Could you create a minimal example dataset that allows to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I think you should just give initial values to the parameters. For exemple, with your exemple, adding p0=[1,1,-10] at the end of curve_fit give good result on my computer.

Comment: @JPG: Oh thanks. That actually worked as well for me! Would you mind just briefly explaining to me what the values in list represent respectively? I am a little confused as to how a parameter in my case can go down to -10.

Comment: I don't understand this -10 value; I just found that the values for `lapse`when it converged were close to -10. But if the value is strange, there is perhaps a mismatch in the datas?